# Interfaces: parametrise over value or use higher-kindedness?

Tags: interface, idris, dependent-type, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to get my head around the difference between these three interfaces, and when to use each

```
interface Foo (xs : List Nat) (n : Nat) bar where
  ...

interface Foo' (xs : List Nat) (bar : Nat -> Type) where
  ...

interface Foo'' (bar : List Nat -> Nat -> Type) where
  ...
```

I assume it's similar to `Functor` vs `Show`, but I'm a bit vague on that too. Any thoughts?

**Context**

I currently use `Foo'`, and I'm using it in a type alias

```
Baz : Foo' xs bar => Type
Baz {bar} = forall m . Vect m Double -> bar m
```

but at usage site I need to specify `xs` twice: `Baz {xs=[1]} {bar=MyFoo [1]}` for some `Foo' xs (MyFoo' xs) where`, which I don't really understand because there's only one possible value that could work for `xs` in the application of `Baz`. I'm exploring the others to see if they work (no success yet), but I'm not very clear on what the API implications of each are.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @michaelmesser I've added my use case. I don't know if it covers everything I need, hence why I asked in the abstract. I appreciate the question may be a little vague w/o the example